# Open Then Control File Python

Tags: python, terminal, emulation

I want to write a scrip to control a terminal emulator (details at this website http://www.mochasoft.dk/tn5250.htm). So far I can open and close the program but I am not able to interact with it. I will need to sendkeystrokes and select data from the emulator. I wrote the syntax I would expect below.

```
import os
os.startfile("somepath\\tn5250.exe")

Set CurScreen = sess0.Screen
CurScreen.WaitForCursor 1, 1
CurScreen.SendKeys ("<Enter>")
CurScreen.MoveTo 36, 33
X = sess0.Screen.Select(1, 36, 1, 33)
print (X)
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Could you make [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) work?

Comment: I'm not sure if you wish to start it with os.startfile() , I believe you are more in the lines of popen() , open a process with shell as true and interact with it programmatically, or using an wrapper like pexpect that @FamousJameous refers to accomplish that, using popen and expecting stdout and acting accordingly